# How can i find roughly time of song from its size

Tags: java, javascript

I have a song say about 5.1 mb ,i want to calculate total duration of song before being played on media player the file format is wave file.

Comment: which format? mp3? ogg? wav? and what bitrate if it's compressed?

Comment: +1 to oedo's comment, we need to know more. The size of the music file is the end-result of many factors (such as comression bitrates), not just the length of the track.

Comment: why is this tagged java / javascript??? I would retag it if I had the slightest idea what tags to actually use...

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the song in order to know the length of it:

```
    URL url = new URL("foo.wav");
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    clip.open(ais);
    System.out.println(clip.getMicrosecondLength());
```

Comment: Hello Samuel,
                  I used this code and got following exception.
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format ULAW 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.
  Please resolve

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really possible based on size. For example, an average MP3 is roughly 1 meg per minute, but if it has been encoded at the full 320 bit rate it can be a lot bigger than that. Your best bet would be to tell your script the size AND duration of the music file.

Comment: My problem is that i have only size available of a particular song.i want total duration may be it can be bit roughly .please suggest

Comment: You could (roughly) divide the duration by 10 for a wav, and use the file size as the duration for mp3. i.e. wavTime = fileSize / 10;

Answer (score 1):

you can try this page : http://www.sounddevices.com/calculator/

for an uncompressed wav - 16 bit, 44.1kHz, stereo, you're looking at 172.2 KB/second, so around 10.332 MB/second. so your file is approx 0.5 minutes